# how to delete individual comment after user clicks on delete?

Tags: angularjs

The following pulls all the comments and displays them:

```
<ul class="comment-list" >
    <li ng-repeat="comment in comments">
      <header>{{ comment.author.name }}</header>
      <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteComment(:id)" value="Delete">
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is what `api/comments` shows:

```
[{"_id":"56255d358cbfdc5f19db8979","author":{"_id":"56255d228cbfdc5f19db8977","name":"user"},"content":"Another comment!","__v":0,"date":"2015-10-19T21:14:29.427Z"},{"_id":"56255d298cbfdc5f19db8978","author":{"_id":"56255d228cbfdc5f19db8977","name":"user"},"content":"Hey.  First comment!","__v":0,"date":"2015-10-19T21:14:17.440Z"}]
```

If I click on delete button, should only delete the one.

Here is what is in controller.js but I don't know what else to add to it.

```
$scope.deleteComment = function() {
      $http.delete('/api/comments/:id');
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

`deleteComment` should delete a comment, right? So it should take a comment as argument:

```
ng-click="deleteComment(comment)"
```

and

```
$scope.deleteComment = function(comment) {
  $http.delete('/api/comments/' + comment._id);
};
```

Comment: thank you sir.  one thing is I am receiving a comment is not defined error.  when I output the comment id by {{ comment._id }} I can see the right ID in the comments taht are loaded.  SIR NEVER MIND.  It was my mistake.  I did not pass comment.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH.  Thank you Sir